# Form validation and Node JS - avoiding pyramid of doom

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I am new to Node and am trying to do some user registration form validation. I would like to refactor the following code to get rid of the pyramid if possible. Im using Express Validator within the userService module to check against empty fields and for email validation, but the isValueUnique function is just a Mongoose findOne query. Im using Graphics Magick to resize the image. Any suggestions most welcome:

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res, next){
  userCheck = userService.checkRegistration(req)
  if(userCheck.errors){
    return res.render('user/register', { 
      errors: userCheck.errors,
      message: req.flash('error'),
      title: 'People Power | Register'
    })
  }
  User.isValueUnique({username: req.body.username}, function(err, user){
    if(user){
      return res.render('user/register', { message: 'Username already taken. Please choose another.', title: 'People Power | Register' });  
    }else{
      User.isValueUnique({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, user){
        if(user){
          return res.render('user/register', { message: 'Email already registered. Please try again.', title: 'People Power | Register' }); 
        } else{
          User.createUser(userCheck, function(err, user){
            if(err) throw err;
            userService.resizeImage(userCheck, function(){
              req.login(user, function(err){
                req.flash('success', 'You have registered successfully, and are now logged in!')
                res.redirect('/')
              })
            });
          });
        }             
      })
    }   
  })             
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [async#waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) to improve "callback hell", so your code might looks like the following:

```
async.waterfall([

    function (callback) {
        User.isValueUnique({username: req.body.username}, callback);
    },

    function (user, callback) {
        if (user) {
            return res.render('user/register', { message: 'Username already taken. Please choose another.', title: 'People Power | Register' });  
        }  
        User.isValueUnique({ email: req.body.email}, callback); 
    }

    function (user, callback) {
        if (user) {
            return res.render('user/register', { message: 'Email already registered. Please try again.', title: 'People Power | Register'};   
        }
        User.createUser(userCheck, callback);
    },

    function (user, callback) {            
        userService.resizeImage(userCheck, callback);            
    },

    function (callback) {
        req.login(user, function(err) {
            req.flash('success', 'You have registered successfully, and are now logged in!')
                res.redirect('/')
            });   
        } 
], function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

Also I suggest to look at [PassportJS](http://passportjs.org/) module that already has suite of patterns for implementation of users registration feature.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I like it alot. I've taken a look at PassportJS and cant see a way to implement validation for fields other than username and password and I cant see an obvious way to validate emails, empty fields etc. Do you know of any examples of using passport beyond the trivial example tutorials that I've seen about?

Comment: Yes sure. There are a lot of examples. I may to advise you this tutorial https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local

Comment: Is the callback function native to async or do we need to define a custom one?

Comment: The callback function is something like `next` function in express middlewares. You should execute is when your partial task has completed to switch the the next one.

Comment: In this tutorial https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall they execute it manualy but in your code it get executed by `isValueUnique` for example

Comment: cheers mate; thanks for your help. I dont think that Passport has much functionality that I've seen outside of the password and username management which seems robust...